# Hbernate : unideirection @onetoone with cascade enable

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a unidirection one to one mapping between Flight(Parent) and Airline(Child),Below is my code-

```
public class Airline {
..
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    Flight flight;
}
```

Flight not have any reference of `Airline` this have id,name their getter and setter.

I am persisting `airline` and cascade is enable.

```
    Flight flight= new Flight();
    flight.setName("flight2");

    Airline airline= new Airline();
    airline.setName("Air India");
    airline.setFlight(flight);

    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(airline);
    session.saveOrUpdate(flight);
```

This throws me exception MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'flights_id' in 'field list'. so I added `@JoinColumn` This worked thanks of answers.

**EDIT----**

But I made a bidirectional without mappedby(ie two unidirectional associations) and didnot applied @joinColumn in second table ie

```
public class Airline {
        @JoinColumn("flight_ref_id")
        @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        Flight flight;
    }


public class Flight {
        @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        Airline airline;
    }
```

And

```
    airline.setFlight(flight);
    flight.setAirLine(airline)
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(airline);
```

Now there is no exception,even no `@joincolumn` in Flight.it created column `airline_id` why?

```
mysql> select * from Airline;
+----+-----------+---------------+
| id | name      | flight_ref_id |
+----+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | Air India |          NULL |
+----+-----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Flight;
+----+--------+------------+
| id | name   | airline_id |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 | Del-NJ |          1 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

And in db `flight_ref_id` is null.why?

Comment: See my edit....

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying the join column name for your db table. Assuming the `airline` table has a join column named `flight_id`, you should use `@JoinColumn` to specify the name -

```
public class Airline {

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "flight_id")
    Flight flight;
}
```

### EDIT

You need to specify `mappedBy` in one side of the relation, like below -

```
public class Flight {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "flight")
    Airline airline;
}
```

where `flight` is the name of the property in the `Airline` entity. This will prevent hibernate to generate foreign key columns on both sides of the relation.

Comment: I dont want to create bidierctional.I just need two way unidirection.

Comment: Err...two way unidirectional _is_ by definition _bidirectional_, no?

Comment: not actually,in bidirection there is single mapping takes care of both side,and ideal to avoid inconsistency,two way uni-direction can cause inconsistency,but this needed in some cases,for example in company there every employee has a single supervisor.A is supervisor of B but reverse is not true ,there is a C for B.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add @JoinColumn annotation to add one more column that serve as flight foreign key

```
public class Airline {
..
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "flights_id", nullable = false)
    Flight flight;
}
```