# SpringBoot JPA MappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

The error: hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

I know why the error is here but the longer i stare at it the more I cannot find it :). I just need another persons perspective.

Here are the MySQL tables:
[image]

Then I have entities for User, Company and Transaction.

The relationships are shown here:

**Transaction:**

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "companyId")
    Company company;
```

**Company**

```
@JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transaction")
    List<Transaction> transactions;
```

**User**

```
@JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transaction")
    List<Transaction> transactions;
```

Here is the full error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: top100.models.Transaction.transaction in top100.models.User.transactions
```

So the error is to do with the relationship but I cannot spot my mistake.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Company**

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
List<Transaction> transactions;
```

**User**

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
List<Transaction> transactions;
```

The mappedBy is referring to the name of the field that is connected to. The link that @Aleksandr Zorin provided has more details. I recommand you to take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you try mapped by field "user".
Probably you may see asked this question in there [Understanding mappedBy annotation in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371481/understanding-mappedby-annotation-in-hibernate][1])

Answer (score 1):

It should be

**Company**

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
List<Transaction> transactions;
```

and

**User**

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
List<Transaction> transactions;
```

In *mappedBy* property you are specifying field in referenced table by which it should be mapped.